# Fingers wont bend with armature

Tags: rigging, armature

[image: fingers won't bend prolerly][image][![enter image description here][3]][3]I'm New to blender 2.79 
I downloaded an obj robot. 
Added the rigify mesh
Everything works ok except the fingers
The armature finger bones works perfect
When I try to connect individual bones to the fingers,each finger shows up as one piece. 
How can I seperate the fingers into 3 portions
Any help would be great

[image]

selecting bone in pose mode
[image]

Comment: could do with at least a few screenshots if not the respective .blend file.

Comment: When I grab each bone to connect to different parts of the finger, it selects the whole finger.

Comment: To make screen shots in blender press Ctrl+F3 and save the image.

Comment: @AmeethRavjee Could you upload your blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can try to help you?

Comment: Ameeth, Did you have trouble uploading the blend file? You emailed me a dropbox link to the file. Normally you just upload it to my website.

Comment: I did have trouble uploading it. It was too big for Yahoo to send

Comment: The file is 192mb

Comment: Sorry man I'm just so frustrated. I can't seem to figure out anything

Comment: I tried uploading to giant cow but it was too big for that as well

Comment: @AmeethRavjee 192 megabytes is huge. Any idea why it is so big? Chances are you can make it a lot smaller.